# Two dates having same values failing when joined in SQL Server 2014 using CONVERT and DATEPART functions

Tags: sql, sql-server-2014

I am facing a very weird problem in joining on two dates in SQL Server 2014. I have a condition like below in my where clause :-

```
SELECT 
    a.*, w.*
FROM
    TABLE1 a, TABLE2 w
WHERE 
    CONVERT(varchar(8), ISNULL(a.Col1,999), 112) + ' ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, DATEPART(hh, ISNULL(a.Col1,999))) + ':' +  RIGHT('0' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, DATEPART(mi, ISNULL(a.Col1,999))), 2) 
= CONVERT(varchar(8),ISNULL(w.Col2,999),112) + ' ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, DATEPART(hh, ISNULL(w.Col2,999))) + ':' +  RIGHT('0' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, DATEPART(mi, ISNULL(w.Col2,999))), 2)
```

Here `Col1` in `Table1` and `Col2` in `Table2` are of type `VARCHAR(18)`.

When selected separately both using the `CONVERT` and `DATEPART` function, both return the same value but when used in a join condition it fails with below error:

> ERROR encountered - 241Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string

Example of Col1 in Table1 data:- "20190227 17:20:40"

Any help is truly appreciated!!

Comment: There are so many things wrong with this query:  commas in the `from` clause, no columns in the `select` use of `varchar` without a length, coalescing a seemingly date value with a number.  Then, the question doesn't provide sample data, desired results, or an explanation of the logic.  I don't see how anyone can provide an answer.

Comment: There is no SQL Server **2015** version - we had 2000, 2005, 2008, 2008 R2, 2012, 2014, 2016, 2017 and soon 2019 - so which one is it that you're using??

Comment: I am using SQL Server 2014, that must have been a typo

Comment: @GordonLinoff: This query runs just fine when not for the join conditions, I am not sure why comma is an issue in FROM clause

Comment: Also, this does not fails but when used with column, it does :- SELECT 1
 WHERE CONVERT(varchar(8),ISNULL('20190227 17:20:40',999),112) + ' ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, DATEPART(hh, ISNULL('20190227 17:20:40',999))) + ':' +  RIGHT('0' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, DATEPART(mi, ISNULL('20190227 17:20:40',999))), 2) 
  = CONVERT(varchar(8),ISNULL('20190227 17:20:40',999),112) + ' ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, DATEPART(hh, ISNULL('20190227 17:20:40',999))) + ':' +  RIGHT('0' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, DATEPART(mi, ISNULL('20190227 17:20:40',999))), 2)

Comment: Why are you using CONVERT() in the join clause at all? You should ideally have an indexed column in each table that you can do the join on. Why not say `WHERE a.col1 = w.col2`? And you shouldn't join NULL columns at all.